# Timeouts updating IRedisDictionary with CachingFramework.Redis

Tags: c#, caching, redis, stackexchange.redis, cachingframework.redis

I have two services that are set-up as CQRS - so one is a query-only service, and the other is a command service that can change data.

The services are backed by MongoDB and also highly parallelised - several queries make use of the aggregation framework and in aggregate can consume large amounts of connections - when they are actually constantly re-reading the same data.

So I thought that Redis would be a good fit for a caching layer on top of MongoDB. I am using the [`CachingFramework.Redis` library](https://github.com/thepirat000/CachingFramework.Redis), which is built on top of [`StackExchange.Redis`](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/).

For the query methods, I create a key object, serialize this to a string and then store/fetch the results using `FetchHashedAsync`. This appears to work well, and I can easily update/invalidate cache items by reconstructing the various keys when a write occurs - when the key can be reconstructed from the main cache item.

Things get more complicated when this is not easily possible; that is to say, when I am caching the results of a general filter query.

Here, my approach thus far was to store a dictionary mapping the filter to the primary keys of the objects that were fetched from MongoDB as a result - and store these in an `IRedisDictionary` instance.

This does not seem to be a very good idea - because I am seeing timeouts as a result:

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException occurred
  HResult=-2146233083
  HelpLink=http://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts
  Message=Timeout performing HSET audit:correlationIdByHash, inst: 2, mgr: ProcessReadQueue, err: never, queue: 609, qu: 0, qs: 456, qc: 153, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 8192, ar: 1, clientName: WSP18652WN, serverEndpoint: Unspecified/localhost:6379, keyHashSlot: 12790, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=9,Free=32758,Min=8,Max=32767) (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: http://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
  Source=StackExchange.Redis
  StackTrace:
       at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
       at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
       at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.HashSet(RedisKey key, RedisValue hashField, RedisValue value, When when, CommandFlags flags)
       at CachingFramework.Redis.RedisObjects.RedisDictionary`2.Add(TK key, TV value)
       at CachingFramework.Redis.RedisObjects.RedisDictionary`2.set_Item(TK key, TV value)
       at SPMO.Providers.Audit.AuditIndex.UpdateIndexImpl(Int32 keyHash, Guid correlationId) in E:\dev\SPMO\trunk\Providers\SPMO.Providers\Audit\AuditIndex.cs:line 61
  InnerException:
```

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: UPDATE: I think this is basically due to the mixing of sync & async calls in the same call tree - I have posted a comment to the GitHub of this library here: https://github.com/thepirat000/CachingFramework.Redis/issues/25

Comment: This was a consequence of a bug on the `CachingFramework.Redis` library (mixing sync & async) and has been fixed now.